# Problem With Java Generic Interface passed to Generic Constructor

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface and a class and both compile just fine.
But when I try to instantiate a Separator with an anonymous implementation of Namer It fails to compile.

```
private interface Namer<N>
{
    String getName(N o);
};

private static class Separator<H>
{
    HashSet<H> oldDiff;
    HashMap<String, H> newFaMap;

    public Separator(HashSet<H> older, HashSet<H> newer, Namer<H> namer)
    {
        oldDiff = new HashSet<H> (older);
        HashSet<H> newDiff = new HashSet<H> (newer);
        oldDiff.removeAll(newer);
        newDiff.removeAll(older);
        newFaMap = makeMap(newDiff, namer);
    }

    private HashMap<String, H> makeMap(HashSet<H> set, Namer<H> namer)
    {
        HashMap<String, H> map = new HashMap<String, H>();
        for (H holder : set)
        {
            map.put(namer.getName(holder), holder);
        }

        return map;
    }
}
```

in a method

```
        Namer<FAHolder> namer = new Namer<FAHolder>() {

            public String getName(FAHolder o)
            {
                return o.getName();
            }
        };

        new Separator<FAHolder>(older, newer, namer);
```

The compile error is:

> The constructor `MyClass.Separator<FAHolder>(Set<FAHolder>, Set<FAHolder>, MyClass.Namer<FAHolder>)` is undefined

What have I overlooked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the static type of `older` and `newer` is `Set<FAHolder>` and not `HashSet<FAHolder>`. Change your constructor's signature from:

```
public Separator(HashSet<H> older, HashSet<H> newer, Namer<H> namer)
```

to

```
public Separator(Set<H> older, Set<H> newer, Namer<H> namer)
```

Comment: I was so focused on the anonymous interface I overlooked the obvious mistake.

Comment: [Program to interfaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) unless you have a need not to.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know the declaration of `older` and `newer` in the constructor calling code, but why you use `HashSet` instead of `Set` in the `Separator` class? Maybe `older` and `newer` are declared as `Set`?

Answer (score 0):

Your older and newer objects seem to be of type "Set" while your constructor parameters are "HashSet".